# Input string was not in a correct format vb net

Tags: vb.net, string, format, invoke

This is really confusing me as I'm not doing anything with Strings.

This is the details the debugger gives back to me:

> System.FormatException was unhandled
>     Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
>     Source=System.Windows.Forms
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
>          at Receiver.Class1.CrossThreadAddControl(Control ControlToAdd, Control BaseControl) in C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Receiver\Receiver\Class1.vb:line 28
>          at Receiver.ContactList.AddContact(Contact user) in C:\Users\Jonathan\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Receiver\Receiver\ContactList.vb:line 25
>          at Receiver.Form1.MySub(IAsyncResult ar) in C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Receiver\Receiver\Form1.vb:line 45
>          at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
>          at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CompleteCallback(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
>          at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(Object result, IntPtr userToken)
>          at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>          at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
>     InnerException:

Basically there is a sub called AddContact in a usercontrol(ContactList) which takes 3 strings and puts them into a another USerControl (Contact) and then adds the Contact to the ContactList
The Contact List is on the main form, and the AddContact Sub is started from a different thread which is why the Invoke thing is needed.

```
    Public Class ContactList

       Sub AddContact(ByVal user As Contact)

        If Me.Controls.Count = 0 Then
            user.Location = New Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        Else
            user.Location = New Drawing.Point(0, Me.Controls.Count * 20)
        End If
        user.Width = Me.Width
        user.Displayname = user.Username
        For Each UC As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf UC Is Contact Then
                If CType(UC, Contact).Username = user.Username Then
                    user.Displayname = user.Username & "@" & user.PCname
                End If

            End If
        Next
        Class1.CrossThreadAddControl(user, Me)

    End Sub
End Class
```

and it is the line with the 2 asterixes (not actaully in the code) which is apparently causing the problems

```
    Shared Sub CrossThreadAddControl(ByVal ControlToAdd As Control, ByVal BaseControl As Control)
    If BaseControl.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New AddUserD(AddressOf AddUser)
    **BaseControl.Invoke(d, ControlToAdd, BaseControl)**



    End If
End Sub
Delegate Sub AddUserD(ByVal ControlToAdd As Control, ByVal BaseControl As Control)
Shared Sub AddUser(ByVal ControlToAdd As Control, ByVal BaseControl As Control)
    BaseControl.Controls.Add(ControlToAdd)
End Sub
```

So any Idea why it saying Input string was not in a correct format?
(oh and if I catch the exception (with Try and Catch) and don't write anything in the catch section it just continues and it works properly without breaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `.Invoke` with `.BeginInvoke` and `.EndInvoke` to get the *real* stacktrace. (Only for debugging purposes, you can change it back later. See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/04/01/2160044.aspx).)